# Maps API v3, markers not clickable with user defined tiles

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

In November 2010 I modified a minecraft-world-map-site for showing huge panorama photos.

My solution for markers worked in November 2010. But now some markers are no more clickable.

Example with JavaScript code inside:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6059427/panorama/beispiel/index.html

The markers on the right side of the photo are not clickable.

I have made a test with Firefox 3.6 and Firebug for exploring this map. There are html-canvas-elements with a fix size of 256x256 pixels. Markers on the right outside of this canvas element are not clickable. Markers on the border of this canvas element have the unexpected property, that only the left half of the marker is clickable, but not the right half.

A single tile is not a perfect square: width 337px, height 323px. I use this rectangle size for displaying broad, expanded panorama photos with a quad tree data structure.

I have tried a lot of solutions/improvements - unfortunately without any success.

What is my mistake? How can I resize this html-canvas-element?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. - Bye. Georg

Answer (score 0):

since the you claim that the code worked in November, you can try to set an older version (e.g. 3.2) of the maps api. It might fix it. For versioning see: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Versioning